# cambiar ruta de formulario laravel 5.4 con jquery

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

tengo el siguiente formulario en una vista :

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>['user.update',$user_id], 'method' => 'PUT']) !!}
{{ Form::close() }}
```

¿Como puedo asignarle el valor de 'user_id' de manera dinámica con jquery?

Este es el HTML que genera el formulario con blade, donde la 'X' es user_id

```
 <form method="POST" action="http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/user/X" 
  accept-charset="UTF-8" id="form_edit">

 <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PUT"><input name="_token" 
  type="hidden" value="UlVvrYf77puFKb5XQutbIZBIqDSaA7F8n9s8D31k">
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar el HTML generado por esa vista. Como no uso Laravel no estoy seguro de qué está dibujando

Comment: así está bien?, gracias por responder

Comment: Podrías usar algo como `$('#form_edit').attr('action', 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/user/'+user_id);`

Comment: si, había pensado hacer eso, pero creo que la plantilla de blade no dibuja el  html de la misma manera, por un tema de rutas... entonces no es lo mismo  **['route'=>['user.update',$user_id]** que **'http://127.0.0.1:8000/public/user/'+user_id)**, espero haberme explicado.. por eso es que quiero ver como poder cambiar o pasar un valor dentro de ese array del form...

Comment: No te recomiendo que uses los forms del paquete collective, el código html se vuelve poco mantenible y no es mucho lo que ayuda al programador. Por cierto, mirate este [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#named-routes), la sintaxis `route('profile', ['id' => 1]);` quizá te sirva. o este [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/helpers#urls)

Comment: Gracias, miraré el link!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a cambiar el tributo `action` del `from` lo mejor es que coloques una id a tu `form` y edites el `action`

```
{!! Form::open(['route'=>['user.update',$user_id], 'method' => 'PUT','id'=>'form_action']) !!}
```

y mediante jquery o javascript accedas y modifiques el atributo. Pero colocando la url base que te da laravel con la función `url('')`

```
$('#form_edit').attr('action', '{{url('')}}/public/user/'+user_id);
```

Así deberías solucionar tu problema.

Inténtalo y nos dices como te fue.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias!